# Appcelerator Titanium - Need Java WebService to receive JavaScript/JSON object and return JSON/XML

Tags: java, web-services, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I need a **Java** WebService that can be used with **Appcelerator Titanium**.

I need to be able to **send** a JavaScript or JSON object and **receive** a JSON object or XML.

I've tried Jax-WS, Jax-RS and Axis2 but no luck. However, if you know how to make it work with any of them, maybe I did something wrong and could use the help to make it work.

Otherwise, does anyone know of a good option?

Thanks in advance.

--- EDIT ---
@pace

Here's what I tried using JAX-RS but I **can't receive** a **JSON object** from a **POST** method with it.

```
   @Path("/getUserByName")
   @POST
   @Consumes("application/json")
   @Produces("application/json")
   public Person getUserByName(@PathParam("name")String name, @PathParam("lastname")String lastname) {
       return new Person(name, 23, lastname);
   }
```

I'm calling the WS with HTTPRequest but that doesn't allow me to send a JSON object.
Any ideas?

--- EDIT 2 ---

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
var url = 'http://10.0.0.114:8080/ClippingExpressMobileWS-JaxRS/usuario/getUsuarioPorNome';
var method = 'POST';

xhr.open('POST', url);

xhr.onload = function() { 

    var json = this.responseText;

    //This is just a printf() or a System.out.println()
    Ti.API.info(json);
}
xhr.onerror = function(e) { 

    alert(e); 
}

var obj = {name: 'Roger', abe: 22, lastname: 'Waters'};

//Then I've tried this:
xhr.send(obj); //This doesn't give any errors on the WS, but the xhr.onerror function is called.
//And this:
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj)); //This gives the error blow.
```

-- Error thrown by xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj))

```
A message body reader for Java class br.com.clippingexpressmobilews.entidades.Pessoa, and Java type class br.com.clippingexpressmobilews.entidades.Pessoa, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
[1/20/12 2:17:59 PM] Natália Oliveira: Jan 20, 2012 2:11:29 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class br.com.clippingexpressmobilews.entidades.Pessoa, and Java type class br.com.clippingexpressmobilews.entidades.Pessoa, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

Again, any ideas? 
And thanks very much for the assistance!

Comment: JAX-RS should be able to do that.  What problem exactly did you run into?

Comment: I just edited the post with information on how I wrote the WS. :)

Comment: When you say you're calling the web service with HTTPRequest do you mean your client library doesn't support JSON?  Are you trying to call into another web service?  Also, your method should be taking in a Person object if you want to receive JSON.  As it stands your method is getting the firstname and lastname from the path but your path doesn't seem setup to provide firstname/lastname.  Have you setup the POJOMappingFeature in your web.xml as described in http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my WebService to match the description on that page. Still, it's not working with the JSON I'm attempting to send. I updated the post again with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method signature to something like below (I'm guessing on the getName and getLastname).  The PathParam annotations are used to get the values from the URL but you don't appear to be doing that.

```
@Path("/getUserByName")
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Person getUserByName(Person input) {
   return new Person(inpug.getName(), 23, input.getLastname());
}
```